# Confusion in NOT IN Operation ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL , how come this operations return `no data found`

```sql
SELECT job_id
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
WHERE job_id NOT IN ('');
```

Shouldn't an empty string means we should get all the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  But not in Oracle.

Oracle treats an empty string as a synonym for `NULL`.  And, because `NOT IN (NULL)` returns `NULL` for any comparison, *nothing* evaluates to TRUE (because `NULL` is not true).

The behavior you expect is correct behavior and how any other database would interpret this.